# How to set typescript for using a connected component in the parent?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux

I created a connected component that uses mapsStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps to inject the properties into the Props (I do not need the parent to inject anything). When I import it in another component typescript complains.

Form.tsx:

```
type IProps = {
  insertError: boolean,
  cleanErrors: () => ICleanErrorsAction,
  addArticle: (arg0: IArticle) => IAddArticleAction
}

type IState = {
  title: string,
  [id:string]: string
}

class ConnectedForm extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      title: ""
    };
  }

  render() {
    // some implementation

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        // some implementation
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
  return {
    addArticle: (article: IArticle) => addArticleAction(article),
    cleanErrors: () => cleanErrorsAction()
  };
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: IStore): any => {
  return state.errors.insertError
}


const Form = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ConnectedForm);
export default Form;
```

And in the parent I use it like `<Form />`.

Typescript raises this error:

`Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<Pick<IProps, "insertError" | "cleanErrors" | "addArticle">>': insertError, cleanErrors, addArticle`

I don't want to put every `Props` field optional in order to avoid null check...

The `props` comes from the connect, I do not need to pass it again. Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: `object as IProps` will help?

Comment: where should I insert it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `mapStateToProps` isn't quite right: this function needs to return an object with properties whose names match the names of the props on the connected component. In your case your connected component is `ConnectedForm` and this is looking for a property called `insertError`. So `mapStateToProps` needs to return an object with this property, as follows:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: IStore) => ({
    insertError: state.errors.insertError
})
```

Two things to note about the above:

1. There are brackets around the curly braces being returned from the function, to let the compiler know that the curly braces represent an object literal, not a code block.
2. You'd marked the function explicitly as returning `any`. This seems to prevent the type inferencing from working correctly, so this needs to be removed: simply don't explicitly define a return type, and the compiler can then infer everything correctly, as per the examples I've linked below.

There is a bit of information about this [here](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#implementing-container-components), and some TypeScript-specific information [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#usage-with-react-redux).